# Finding AAD Application permissions for all subscriptions as the owner?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

If I am the owner of an AAD application that has Azure RBAC role assignments subscriptions that my user account isn't a part of, how can I (either portal or Powershell) check what those assignments are?

Comment: What is the "subscriptions" mean ?Do you want to know which user has been assigned the application role ?

Comment: Yes, I have an application that's been assigned a role for a subscription.  I own the application, but my user account doesn't have access to the subscription it's role is for.